# Will pausing HD videos for multiple hours cause any damage to the hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive, vlc-media-player

The latest VLC media player has a feature to resume from where I had to stop. But I had to pause the HD video, which is more than 1 GB, to go to work for a couple hours. Will this cause any damage to the hard disk?

I am asking because VCR's stop after a long pause.

Comment: Absolutely not, I do it all the time.

Comment: Why would you think it would cause damage? Is there another issue you are dealing with that would make you think that some situation like this would be the case?

Comment: @Furty I made major changes to my **question**.

Comment: Thanks, i suggest you remove mentioning a special software resume feature (only applied when VLC/SMPlayer is closed!) when asking about hardware

Comment: @BlueApple Other good answers explain the hard drive part. But the thing with VCRs — if anyone remembers them — is there was a constantly spinning read/write head in addition to the spools moving for the tape. Meaning that if you paused a VCR the spools would stop moving, but the head would keep on spinning and spinning. And that could potentially wear out the head as well as the tape it is reading from. Additionally there were other guiding poles (too lazy to look up the tech name for them) that the tape would be wrapped around. If they sat there too long, there’s another risk of tape damage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pause a video that's being played from the HD the data is no longer read, as the data is not being used it doesn't need to be read, it will only start reading again once you press play again, so there shouldn't be any problems caused to your system.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the code of VLC but I am still confident to say no. No damage at all.

I suspect when you pause VLC will remember the offset (the point in the data file you stopped). This is likely reserved in memory but could be written to file. If the latter, I don't think a single write (and then read if you resume) will cause much difference to the HDD.

The only damage could be by having a static image on the screen for a long time but it depends on what monitor you have